# Rally APIs: Java: how to find parent test folder of a test folder in rally

Tags: java, rally

On requesting for a test folder, the JSON object won't have reference to its parent test folder. Is there any way we can find the parent test folder using java apis?

Answer (score 0):

Parent attribute on TestFolder object is a reference to the parent test folder. It is available if the TestFolder object is either fully hydrated using `fetch=true`, or when Parent field is explicitly fetched using `fetch=parent`. For example this endpoint:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/testfolder?query=(FormattedID = TF2)&fetch=parent
```

returns this json:

```
{
QueryResult: {
_rallyAPIMajor: "2",
_rallyAPIMinor: "0",
Errors: [ ],
Warnings: [ ],
TotalResultCount: 1,
StartIndex: 1,
PageSize: 20,
Results: [
{
_rallyAPIMajor: "2",
_rallyAPIMinor: "0",
_ref: "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/testfolder/62107128679",
_refObjectUUID: "285c564b-f66a-40e0-88fd-f5c9432d0f34",
_objectVersion: "1",
_refObjectName: "folder2",
Parent: {
_rallyAPIMajor: "2",
_rallyAPIMinor: "0",
_ref: "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/testfolder/62107127642",
_refObjectUUID: "ed334288-4815-4472-ab28-bc3cb0030114",
_objectVersion: "1",
_refObjectName: "folder1",
_type: "TestFolder"
},
_type: "TestFolder"
}
]
}
}
```

In your java code when you query on a test folder you need to fetch Parent field.